# C throw compiler warning (clang) if transitively included function is used

Tags: c, clang

I have three classes and corresponding header files, user.c, foo.c, and util.c. util.c contains functions that foo.c depends on, but I would prefer that user.c not call. Ideally, user.c would only be calling functions in foo.c. Right now, user.h/.c includes foo.h/.c, which includes util.h/.c, so all of the util functions are included transitively in user.c.

I don't need to keep the util.c contents hidden from the user, but I was wondering if there was a way to throw a compiler error/warning (or something like that) with clang if user.c ever calls something from util.c. Is this possible?

I've seen some things about PIMPL to hide private headers, but would rather not handle the additional memory and other tradeoffs of that.

I have the following includes:
user.c

```
#include user.h
foofunction(); //can call both of these just fine
utilfunction(); //would like to have a compiler warning if this is called
```

user.h

```
#include foo.h
```

foo.c

```
#include foo.h
void foofunction(){utilfunction();};
```

foo.h

```
#include util.h
void foofunction();
```

util.h

```
#include util.c
void utilfunction();
```

util.c

```
//no includes, just some functions
void utilfunction(){};
```

Comment: Do not include `util.h` in `foo.h`. Include `util.h` in `foo.c`.

Comment: You should not be including any `.c` file in any other `.c` file.  Headers should declare, but not define, functions; ditto variables.  Note that 'classes' and 'PIMPL' are most commonly associated with C++, not C.  You'd do best to stay clear of that nomenclature if you are working in C.

Comment: There are lots of things you could be doing — right and wrong.  It would be easier to help you if you showed an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  If any of the `.c` files includes any other `.c` file (or includes itself), then you have major design issues.  There are various ways of keeping things simple — 'opaque types' in C correspond, more or less, to the PIMPL idiom in C++.

Answer (score 0):

For C, there isn't any protection to any API/variables as long as it is global.  In order to not expose API in other files you should:

- Should not include private file in .h. All includes are perform in .c file
- In case don't want user include private .h file, it is possible that you created a `#define` and check for the existence in private .h file and throw #error if not existence.